# add smtp to php mail function using phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i'm trying to add smtp authentication using phpmailer. i'm new to php and i'm struggling to accomplish this.
i have this code:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $to = $_POST['budget'].',test@test.ro';
    $subject = 'Programare servicii'; 
    $message = 'Nume: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                         'Prenume: ' . $_POST['company']. "\n" .
                         'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email']. "\n" .
                         'Telefon: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n\n" .
                         'Doresc: ' . $_POST['interested']. "\n" .
                         'Magazin: ' . $_POST['budget']. "\n" .
                         'Incepand cu: ' . $_POST['start']. "\n" .
                         'Pana la: ' . $_POST['finish']. "\n" .
                         'Observatii: ' . $_POST['comment']. "\n\n\n";



  $num = md5(time());
  $headers = 'From:' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
  $headers .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
  $headers .= "--$num\r\n";$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
  $headers .= "$message\r\n";
  $headers .= "--$num\r\n";

    if( isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) )
    {

        $file = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
      $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
      $content = fread($file, $size);
      $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));      

        $headers .= "Content-Type: ". $_FILES['file']['type'] ."; ";
        $headers .= 'name="' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . '"' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
        $headers .= 'filename="' . $_FILES['file']['name'] . '"' . "\r\n\n";
        $headers .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
        $headers .= "--$num--";
    }
    mail($to, $subject, '', $headers);
}
?>
```

how do id add authentication? any ideas? i read the phpmailer examples and i was able to send an authenticated email with phpmailer. the problem is that i can't get the code above to work with smtp authentication. i have a dropdown in my form and from there the user can select a store and the script will send email to that store. when i add $_POST['email'] to $mail->addAddress nothing happens.
Thanks for your time,

Bogdan

update 1:
i mange to do this:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                               
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
$mail->Username = 'test@test.ro';           
$mail->Password = 'pass';     
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
$mail->Port = 587;           
$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
$mail->addAddress('need to get data from form', 'iohan test');   
$mail->addReplyTo('test@test.ro', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('test@test.ro');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                
$mail->Subject = 'test iohan';
$mail->Body    = 'bla bla bla';
$mail->AltBody = 'bla bla';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

the question is how to make it work. i have a drop-down with multiple emails and i need to send emails to the email the user selected.

Comment: Please cut your code down to the minimum needed to explain your problem, and add some more details of what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: i'm trying to add smtp authentication to the php code above using php mailer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple problem here. You're not using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer); you're using PHP's `mail()` function, which is not the same thing at all, and does not suport authentication because it does not use SMTP. I'd really recommend you don't even try doing this yourself; let PHPMailer do it for you. The example in the readme file should be enough to get you going.

All that stuff you're doing with headers, creating the message body, encoding attachments, etc is not necessary. Your code is also vulnerable to header injection attacks and may have incorrectly encoded headers. You're also not handling file uploads safely - read the PHP docs on that, or look at the 'send file upload' example provided with PHPMailer.

Assuming your form looks like this (you should not get the destination email from the form directly because it opens it to abuse as a spam gateway):

```
<select name="to">
    <option value="0">sales@example.com</option>
    <option value="1" selected>support@example.com</option>
    <option value="2">billing@example.com</option>
</select>
```

You could process that like this:

```
$to = [
    0 => 'sales@example.com',
    1 => 'support@example.com',
    2 => 'billing@example.com',
];
$mail->addAddress($to[$_POST['to']]);
```

though you should do some validation too.

In the code you posted you're setting `$mail->From` using data form the form - you should not do that as it will cause the message to fail SPF checks; use a fixed from address and stick the sender's address into a reply-to.

Comment: i now i'm using the php mail function. what i need is to convert the code above to phpmailer. any ideas?

Comment: Uh, read the docs and examples? They tell you how to do all that your code does, and lots more.

Comment: done that, but i did not manage to use variables to send emails to what the users selects.

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you have not posted your code? What's in the question appears to be entirely irrelevant to what you want!

Comment: i have the code above. i need to convert that in phpmailer code. i use the exemple code from phpmailer to see if all is good an my server and i manage to send email. now i what to convert the above code in phpmailercode to send emails

Comment: Don't 'convert' it. Start again using one of the PHPMailer examples. At least *try* to do it yourself - we're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: ok. i manage to do something. code is above. but i cant figure out how to get data from form drop-down. i have multiple emails in drop-down, and i need to send emails to the email the user selected.